# AVD could not move on the screen

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I just created an AVD but the startup screen is blank and could not move on the screen. My setting is like below:

Android 5.0.1 arm
Scale: 4dp on device
RAM: 512 MB
VM heap: 128 MB

Comment: That's perfectly normal. An arm image will take forever to load. You must use the intel haxm emulator instead. Search on StackOverflow for instructions on how to install that.

Answer (score 27):

I think the title of your AVD windown may be moved to out of screen, can not use mouse to drag it down, you can use following steps to move it down via keyboard.

1. Select AVD window by mouse
2. Press Alt and Space key, then a menu will appear on AVD window
3. select Move
4. use your arrow key to move it down (you should use down arrow key)

Comment: As opposed to other methods this actually works. You have to use the down arrow key, moving mouse alone doesn't do any good.

Answer (score 4):

This might help

In window,

```
Press ALT + SPACE + M and move the windows by press UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT .
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out a way for this.

Go to settings of AVD and Enable "Show window frame around device". Once this is enabled, you can easily drag it anywhere you like. Even take it out of window. See the images below:

[image]

[image]