# Android Studio 1.2 Emulator fits to one end of the screen and not moving

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have installed new Android Studio V 1.2  and tried launching my First App.
The emulator which shows up is fitting to the Top Left corner of the screen and is not moving.

This happens only in this version and in Windows only. Did someone face the same isse and resolved it ??

AVD Details:
Name: Nexus 5 API 21 x86
Using the Default one. Also tried creating different AVDs . **All fits to Top Left corner of the screen and is not Movable**

Tried Restarting
There is no **Auto Fit to Screen Size** option now.
Any remedy ? Puzzled

Log States
emulator: device fd:660
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode

Comment: Did you try to turn it off and on again? But seriously why are you not using stable version?

Comment: Tried Restarting. There is one more update. I used the one before the latest.

Answer (score 8):

I think the title of your AVD windown may be moved to out of screen, can not use mouse to drag it down, you can use following steps to move it down via keyboard.

1. Select AVD window by mouse
2. Press Alt and Space key, then a menu will appear on AVD window
3. select Move
4. use your arrow key to move it down (you should use down arrow key)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29292949/4255980

Answer (score 3):

Press ALT + SPACE + M and move the windows by press UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT and it will work.

Have fun ;)